# Customize formatter with abstraction

Tags: c++, std, c++20, fmt

I am trying the following ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/cd57cd1d4)):

```
#include <string>
#include <format> // For std::format
#include <fmt/format.h> // For fmt::format
#include <ranges>
#include <functional>

struct Point {
    int x; 
    int y;
};


#ifdef USE_FMT
template<typename T>
struct Formatter : public fmt::formatter<T> {};
using context = fmt::format_context;
#else 
template<typename T>
struct Formatter : public std::formatter<T> {};
using context = std::format_context;

#endif

template <>
struct Formatter<Point>:  Formatter<std::string>
{
    auto format(Point x,
                context& ctx) const
    {
        return Formatter<std::string>::format(std::to_string(x.x) + "us", ctx);
    }
};

int main() {
    Point xx {2,3};

    std::cout << std::format("{}", xx); // assuming using std 

    return 0;
}
```

But it fails to compile. As indicated in the above code, I want to let the developer to custom format using the `struct Formatter` where the backend can then choose which backend solution to employ.

Any reasons why this fails and possible solutions to this?

Compiler error:

> In file included from
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240207/include/c++/14.0.1/ostream:43,
> from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240207/include/c++/14.0.1/iostream:41,
> from :1: /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240207/include/c++/14.0.1/format:
> In instantiation of 'class std::__format::_Checking_scanner<char,
> Point>':
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240207/include/c++/14.0.1/format:4174:4:
> required from 'consteval std::basic_format_string<_CharT,
> _Args>::basic_format_string(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = char [3]; _CharT = char; _Args = {Point&}]'  4174 |           __scanner(_M_str);
> |           ^~~~~~~~~ :38:29:   required from here    38 |     std::cout << std::format("{}", xx); // assuming using std
> |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~ /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240207/include/c++/14.0.1/format:4030:10:
> error: static assertion failed: std::formatter must be specialized for
> each type being formatted  4030 |
> (is_default_constructible_v<formatter<_Args, _CharT>> && ...),

Comment: If compilation fails, include relevant error messages. These provide information about _why_ compilation failed, and you should always read them. If you don't understand them, that's even more reason to include the messages in your question. Don't expect people to visit off-site links to reveal crucial details about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for a non-specialized formatter will raise these kinds of errors, indicating that you have not actually specialized a formatter for that type. This is documented in [`std::formatter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter):

> For all types T and CharT for which no specialization `std::formatter<T, CharT>` is enabled, that specialization is a complete type and is disabled.
>
> Disabled specializations do not meet the [*Formatter*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Formatter) requirements, and the following are all `false`:
>
> - [`std::is_default_constructible_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible)
> - [`std::is_copy_constructible_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible)
> - [`std::is_move_constructible_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible)
> - [`std::is_copy_assignable_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_assignable)
> - [`std::is_move_assignable_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_assignable)

The problem here is that you are not specializing `std::formatter`, but instead defining your *own* class template that derives from `std::formatter` and specializing *that*. When you invoke `std::format` it has no way of finding your `Formatter` specializations.

The same applies to `fmt::format`.

Additionally, your program is always using `std::format` here, despite having logic to choose the format library based on the macro `USE_FMT`. If you define that macro, you'll run into further issues because `std::format` does not look for `fmt::formatter` specializations.

You need to directly specialize `std::formatter` (or `fmt::formatter`). Here's how you could do it cleanly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifdef USE_FMT
#   include <fmt/format.h>      // For fmt::format
#   define FMT_NAMESPACE fmt
#else
#   include <format>            // For std::format
#   define FMT_NAMESPACE std
#endif

using FMT_NAMESPACE::format;

struct Point {
    int x; 
    int y;
};

template <>
struct FMT_NAMESPACE::formatter<Point> : formatter<std::string>
{
    auto format(Point x, format_context& ctx) const
    {
        return formatter<std::string>::format(std::to_string(x.x) + "us", ctx);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Point xx {2,3};
    std::cout << format("{}", xx);
}
```